# automated test, code coverage, static analysis and codereview

Tags: plugins, jenkins, code-coverage

I used to be developer long ago but for last 10 years working on system ops. I am planning to move into devops and trying to sharpen my saw. However, when it comes to jenkins and specially static code analysis, code coverage, automated test and code review, I get so much confused.

Lets start from automated test ( for simplicity take unit test). I understand that we write a separate class file for unit test. But how does that test is carried out? Will jenkins create a jvm where the newly build artifact is deployed and the tests are run against it? or will the test be run against code ( I do not think but still want to clarify)?

I downloaded one example application with maven and codertura from github and build the project. When the build was completed, it publishes code coverage report.

I have not done any post build, for deploying the artifact. So, I am not sure how it works, and what did it do and how?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

Here is a common flow that you can follow to achieve your requirement.

Work with code --> Push to [gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) for review --> [Jenkins gerrit trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) plugin get triggered --> The corresponding job will checkout the code you committed and do the compile, package, unit test, deploy to [artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) --> Execute the [sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) build to analysis the code quality, static analysis, code coverage...

Br,

Tim

Comment: I understand the basic flow now.  As I also mentioned in my post, my confusion is at what point and how the automated test is carried out?  In my limited understanding, the test is carried out/conducted on the deployed application but how is this automated test done in while building? 

Thanks